# Element not allowed in content model

Tags: xml, validation, schema

there.

I'm trying to validate a xml document with a schema made by myself and I keep getting this error:
**Validation stopped at line 40, column 12: element 'article' is not allowed for content model '(book*|article*|mastersthesis*|inproceedings*)'**

My xsd file is well-formed, so as my xml file. The line 40 is just the end of my xml document (`</bibEntry>` ).

This is part of my xsd file:

```
<xs:element name="bibEntry" type="entryType"/>
 <xs:complexType name="entryType">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element ref="book" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element ref="article" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element ref="mastersthesis" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element ref="inproceedings" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:choice>
 </xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="publisher" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="year" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="edition" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="ISBN" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="journal" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="volume" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
<xs:element name="number" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
<xs:element name="pages" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="school" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="booktitle" type="xs:string"/>

<xs:element name="book" type="bookType"/>
 <xs:complexType name="bookType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="author"/>
    <xs:element ref="title"/>
    <xs:element ref="publisher"/>
    <xs:element ref="year"/>
    <xs:element ref="edition"/>
    <xs:element ref="ISBN"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:element name="article" type="articleType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="articleType" mixed="true">
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="author"/>
    <xs:element ref="title"/>
    <xs:element ref="year"/>
    <xs:element ref="journal"/>
    <xs:element ref="volume"/>
    <xs:element ref="number"/>
    <xs:element ref="pages"/>
   </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
 </xs:complexType>
```

And this is my xml:

```
<bibEntry xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com bibEntry.xsd">

  <book>
    <author>José Saramago</author>
    <title>Ensaio Sobre a Cegueira</title>
    <publisher>Caminho</publisher>
    <year>1995</year>
    <edition>1ª</edition>
    <ISBN>9722110217</ISBN>
  </book>

  <article>
    <author>Regev, Oded</author>
    <title>On Lattices, learning with errors, random linear codes and cryptography</title>
    <year>2009</year>
    <journal>Journal of the ACM</journal>
    <volume>56</volume>
    <number>13</number>
    <pages>34</pages>
  </article>

  <mastersthesis>
    <author>Menno den Hollander</author>
    <title>Automatic Unit Test Generation</title>
    <school>Delft University of Technology</school>
    <year>2010</year>
  </mastersthesis>

  <inproceedings>
    <author>Thomas Tilley</author>
    <title>Tool Support for FCA</title>
    <booktitle>ICFCA</booktitle>
    <year>2004</year>
    <pages>104-111</pages>
  </inproceedings>

</bibEntry>
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error suggests that your XML is violating the rules that you established in the schema, so I think we need to see the XML.

Comment: Your schema may be well-formed, but it's still not valid.  You're missing element declarations for 'mastersthesis' and 'inproceedings'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you close your element tags too soon.
Instead of

```
<xs:element name="article" type="articleType"/>
```

try

```
<xs:element name="article" type="articleType">
 (....)
</xs:element>
```